# Regex with recursive expression to match nested braces?

Tags: regex, perl, recursion

I'm trying to match text like `sp { ...{...}... }`, where the curly braces are allowed to nest. This is what I have so far:

```
my $regex = qr/
(                   #save $1
    sp\s+           #start Soar production
    (               #save $2
        \{          #opening brace
        [^{}]*      #anything but braces
        \}          #closing brace  
        | (?1)      #or nested braces
    )+              #0 or more
)
/x;
```

I just cannot get it to match the following text: `sp { { word } }`. Can anyone see what is wrong with my regex?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are numerous problems. The recursive bit should be:

```
(
   (?: \{ (?-1) \}
   |   [^{}]+
   )*
)
```

All together:

```
my $regex = qr/
   sp\s+
   \{
      (
         (?: \{ (?-1) \}
         |   [^{}]++
         )*
      )
   \}
/x;

print "$1\n" if 'sp { { word } }' =~ /($regex)/;
```

Comment: As near as I can tell, the regex doesn't allow spaces around the braces (sorry for the rhyme) so the test case should fail.  What's up with that?

Comment: Hmmm... This ends up taking forever for some partial matches, like this: `sp {word{(aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa)}`.

Comment: @NateGlenn see my solution, also what do you want to happen on that partial match, is that a failure or would you have it return the remainder of the string?

Comment: @JoelBerger that one should not match. The rest of the matches should be returned.

Comment: Speed issue fixed by changing `[^{}]+` to `[^{}]++`.

Comment: Thanks! Succeeds/fails like lightning.

Answer (score 6):

This is case for the underused [`Text::Balanced`](http://p3rl.org/Text%3a%3aBalanced), a very handy core module for this kind of thing. It does rely on the [`pos`](http://p3rl.org/pos) of the start of the delimited sequence being found/set first, so I typically invoke it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::Balanced 'extract_bracketed';

sub get_bracketed {
  my $str = shift;

  # seek to beginning of bracket
  return undef unless $str =~ /(sp\s+)(?={)/gc;

  # store the prefix
  my $prefix = $1;

  # get everything from the start brace to the matching end brace
  my ($bracketed) = extract_bracketed( $str, '{}');

  # no closing brace found
  return undef unless $bracketed;

  # return the whole match
  return $prefix . $bracketed;
}

my $str = 'sp { { word } }';

print get_bracketed $str;
```

The regex with the `gc` modifier tells the string to remember where the end point of the match is, and `extract_bracketed` uses that information to know where to start.

Comment: I really need to read up on this module. It comes up a lot, but I always prefer regex because I've already invested so much time in learning it, it's fun to learn more of, and seems more compact. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @NateGlenn, it really is complementary to regexp and especially the regexp `gc` (parser) functionality. This is why it uses the `pos` of the string, because it is expected that you will intermingle the calls to `text_balanced` with `//gc`