# Changing a regex to avoid quoted tokens

Tags: regex, perl, quote

I have a handy-dandy regex provided from a [previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719935/regex-with-recursive-expression-to-match-nested-braces):

```
$regex = qr/
    (sp\s+              #start with 'sp'        
    \{                  #opening brace
      (                 #save to $2
         (?:            #either
            \{ (?-1) \} #more braces and recurse
            |           #or
            [^{}]++     #non-brace characters
         )*             #0 or more times
      )                 #end $2
    \}                  #ending brace
    )                   #end $1
    /x;
```

I use it to extract textual structures from a file which are of the form `sp {}`, with possible further nesting of the curly braces. It correctly saves the following text in $1:

```
sp {foo {bar} baz}
```

But I've run into a problem: quoting. In the text I have, vertical bars can be used to quote:

```
sp {foo |}}}}bar}}}{{|}
```

That entire thing is one structure, but the current regex I have will only match `sp {foo |}`. The matter is further complicated because a vertical bar can be escaped within a quote
using a backslash:

```
sp {foo |}\|bar|}
```

should also match. Does anyone have any ideas on how to soup-up this regex to handle quotes and quote escaping?

Comment: ...write a parser? While it may be possible with a regex, this seems like it will get far too complicated.

Comment: yeah... I guess I've been looking for an excuse to learn Regex::Grammar anyways...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
[^{}]
```

with

```
(?: [^|{}]++
|   \| (?: [^\\|]++ | \\. )*+ \|
)
```

Comment: Close... it's not quite right if there are double braces in the quote: `sp {|}}|)}`

Answer (score 1):

Look at a CPAN module like Text::Balanced.

Comment: That was my answer to the original question! And BTW Text::Balanced is core.

Comment: @NateGlenn, though as I look, I'm not sure it can handle custom escape characters on a bracketed pattern, though it can on a delimited ('') pattern.