# perl splitting a string

Tags: perl, parentheses, split

I realize that I did not make the title good enough, but I am not getting any better.

Assume there is a string

```
$str = "(aa)(bb)(cc)(dd)(ee)";
```

That is, there are substrings, enclosed in parenthesis, there is no space between the parenthesis groups, i.e. like (*)(*), but inside the parenthesis, where i wrote aa, bb, cc, etc, there can be spaces. Parenthesis may be nested, but that is not absolutely important. but there are unknown number of parenthesis groups.

Now I want to split the string in an array of strings, each element having a (balanced) parenthesis enclosed element . that is,

```
# @arr contains now ("(aa)", "(bb)", "(cc)" .. etc)
```

of course i can implement a counter based method, but wont perl, being perl, have some built in methods for this? I dont quite know how this particular operation called, so i dont know what to look for, string splitting is too general, no?

edit: splitting parentheses delimmited string in perl <--- searching this is not returning me anything useful, i guess this is due to the fact it is not really DELIMITED, enclosed?

Comment: What have your tried so far. Stackoverflow is not a code writing service but its members are happy to help you improve you own attempts. Also, please give an example of how you want nested parenthesis handled.

Comment: as i said, I have a counter based implementation, and i am asking if perl already has a built in function or instruction for this. I would be happy with any hint, i did not quite ask for a code writing service (must be my bad english). As for the nested elements, I want to extract them in a balanced manner, that is (a(bb)c)(dd) will make (a(bb)c) and (dd), that is the only balanced extraction no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@arr= map { "$_)" } split /\)/, $str;
```

This method strips the ending parenthesee, but then adds it back.

Another way is with the 'global' flag on a regex, which returns all matches.

```
@arr= ( $str =~ /\([^)]*\)/g )
```

Comment: ah the global flag, that is a nice one, thank you, i will check this now

Comment: I see now that you also wanted matched **nested** parenthesees... Other questions here have answered how to write those.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719935/regex-with-recursive-expression-to-match-nested-braces

Comment: thank you both, the g option worked perfect. so i will choose this one as the answer as it was the first one.

Answer (score 1):

There are several suggestions.

For example the first:

```
use strict;

my $str = "(aa)(bb)(cc)(dd)(ee)";
my @arr;

while ($str =~ /(\(.*?\))/ig) {
    push @arr, $1;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If we ignore nesting, what you want to do is split between `)` and `(`.

```
my @arr = split /(?<=\()(?=\()/, $str;
```

Instead of splitting, you could also extract the parts.

```
my @arr = $str =~ /( \( [^()]* \) )/xg;
```

Matching nested parens is just a matter of applying this regex pattern recursively.

```
my @arr = $str =~ /\G ( \( (?: [^()]++ | (?1) )* \) )/xg;
```